# Alfresco html tag properties plain text search

Tags: html, search, properties, alfresco

I want to do plain text seach in html files. 
It seems that properties values are not indexed. 
if i have a html file containing  tag like this `<div property="property value"> Textual value </div>` i can't found this file by searching property value. 
Is there a way to make this possible ?

Comment: You mean out of box search is not able to find this html based on text? Like to mention here that file contents and meta-data are indexed differently. So, I think you are expecting to search content just like meta-data.

Comment: Hi  Mitpatoliya. 

Search on  div text value return  files i'm looking for. But not search on tag propertie. Do you understand my mean? 


I don't wanna search on metadata but on content  (specialy on tag property value)

Answer (score 4):

You need to define your own custom metadata extracter.You can fine more information on below link.

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Metadata_Extraction

For your requirement,

```
alfresco-community-sdk-3.4.b\src\alfresco-repository-src.zip\java\org\alfresco\repo\content\metadata\HtmlMetadataExtracter.java
```

Above is the class which is responsible for extracting data from the html file.If you see the content of that file it is neglecting tags and attributes inside tag.So you can take reference of above file and define your own `Metadata Extractor`

Comment: Hi ,

First I want to know if this scenario is Normal. ie natively Alfresco can not search the HTML tag attributes  value?

Comment: If so i will see if i must modify java code (I do not want to get into  java code modification because it seems complexe for me now)

Comment: Well, as per my knowledge ,I dont think there will be another way for that